# The app freezes only in signed apk with Marshmallow OS

Tags: android, apk, release, android-6.0-marshmallow, signed

Our application is running very well in the debug mode on all devices even on Marshmallow devices. But after generating the signed apk the app freezes.
after adding some logs and following them , We found that the app freezes in the line that we add the content of the tabs in.

this is a snippet of the code

```
tabhost = (TabHost) view.findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
content = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.content);
tabhost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
tabhost.setup();

tabhost.addTab(tabhost.newTabSpec(res.getString(R.string.all))
                .setIndicator(res.getString(R.string.all))
                .setContent(new TabContentFactory() {
                    public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                        Log.e("TAG", tag); // The last line appears in the log
                        return listView;
                    }
                }));
        Log.e("TAG", "end"); // this log doesn't appear in log in the signed version.
```

the listview is not null , we are sure of that

Any suggestions ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you implemented proguard in your app?

Comment: No, we are not implementing proguard in our app.

Comment: May be tabhost is slow or something. You can try
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html

Comment: I'll give it a try and tell you the result . Thank you @Yousef Khan

Comment: remove `return listView;` this line and try it

Comment: @Anand I already tried to return only a `textview` that is locally created in `CreateTabContent` function , and it didn't work.
I also tried to check if the `listview `is null or not and I found that it is not null.

Comment: @NayraAhmed : reply tabhost with tablayout and check it